# List all combinations for x length

Tags: javascript, function

I have created a function that is supposed to list all number combinations for x length. The only problem is that it does nothing and I can't see why.

Function:

```
function combos(l) {
    var o = '', max = '', tmp = '', out = [];
    for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++) {
        o+='0';
        max+='9';
    }
    max = +max;
    for(var j=0;j<max;j++) {
        console.log(o.split('').join(' - '));
        tmp = o++;
        while ((''+tmp).length != l) {
            tmp = '0' + tmp;
        }
        o = tmp;
        out.push(o);
    }
    return out;
}
```

The expected output of `combos(2)` would be:

```
0 - 0
0 - 1
0 - 2
...
9 - 7
9 - 8
9 - 9
```

Along with an array of each entry.

Why won't this work?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? It shouldn't be too hard to find the problem by setting some breakpoints and inspect the variables. And something you can easily do yourself.

Comment: What is the output that you *do* get?

Comment: @FelixKling I put `console.log()`s after each assignment. `max` is saying it's 0. Just don't know why.

Comment: For one thing, `l.length` is a strange call on a `2` passed in.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Good spotting, that was the problem.

Comment: If you had set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and stepped through to, you probably would have noticed that the first loop is not executed.

Comment: another point is: `o` seems to be a string, so `o++` would not make much sense.

Comment: @derpirscher Open up your console and run `var n = '33'`. If you then do `n++` and check `n` again, it'll be `34`.

Comment: @Spedwards Ah ok. It's a string just with numbers. Then this would work. Thanks for the comment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if the input is a number (combos(2))

```
for(var i=0;i<l;i++) {
```

instead of

```
for(var i=0;i<l.length;i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question, you can simplify your code:

```
String.prototype.lpad = function(length) {
    str = this
    while (str.length < length)
        str = '0' + str;
    return str;
}

function combos(l) {
    var num = 0;
    var str = '0'.lpad(l);
    var out = [];
    do {
       out.push(str);
       str = String(++num).lpad(l);
    } while (str.length <= l)
    return out;
}
```